# List of 2 columns as column data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table like:

```
foo <- data.table(a = c(1,2,3), b = c(4,5,6))
```

I want to add another column c which is by row/record a list of `a` and `b`. Something like:

```
data.table(a = c(1,2,3), b = c(4,5,6), c = c(list(1,4), list(2,5), list(3,6)))
```

but even in the example it only take one element and recycle

```
   a b c
1: 1 4 1
2: 2 5 4
3: 3 6 2
4: 1 4 5
5: 2 5 3
6: 3 6 6
```

However I want:

```
   a b c
1: 1 4 list(1,4)
2: 2 5 list(2,5)
3: 3 6 list(3,6)
```

I tried also:

```
foo$c <- foo[, list('a' = a, 'b' = b)]
foo$c <- foo[, list('a' = a, 'b' = b), by = 1:nrow(foo)]
foo$c <- as.list(foo[, list('a' = a, 'b' = b)])
```

Nothing works.

Comment: `foo[, c := .(.(.BY)), by = .(a, b)]`

Comment: @DavidArenburg bang on. If you wish, you can make it a answer.

Comment: If you want a vector instead of a list, there's `foo[, c := as.list(transpose(.SD)), .SDcols = a:b]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use `Map` and `list`:

```
foo[, c := Map(list, a, b)][]

#   a b      c
#1: 1 4 <list>
#2: 2 5 <list>
#3: 3 6 <list>
```

And column `c` is a list of lists:

```
dput(foo$c)
# list(list(1, 4), list(2, 5), list(3, 6))
```

To keep the names:

```
foo[, c := Map(list, a=a, b=b)][]
#   a b      c
#1: 1 4 <list>
#2: 2 5 <list>
#3: 3 6 <list>

dput(foo$c)
# list(list(a = 1, b = 4), list(a = 2, b = 5), list(a = 3, b = 6))
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this programmatically using .SDcols? e.g. if you have a longer list of colnames.

Answer (score 1):

Using `list` instead of `c` seems to work:

```
data.table(a = c(1,2,3), b = c(4,5,6), c = list(list(1,4), list(2,5), list(3,6))) 
   a b      c
1: 1 4 <list>
2: 2 5 <list>
3: 3 6 <list>
```

Comment: This has to do with the way the third column was defined. When you call `c` the arguments form a vector.  In R you can have a list of vectors but not a vector of lists.